# How do I get a log of commands eat a specified cpu like 80%

Tags: bash, cpu-load

This image comes from an issue disscussion on [github](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/1843)

[image]

I guess it was generated by some kind of dashboard.

Is it possible to get this information by using some commands and bash on Ubuntu?

I tried to use this command

```
top -b > ~/cpu.txt
```

and analyze the file "cpu.txt", which doesn't work.

Because my program is running on a VM guest on which top command looks good while the monitor on my host indicates the guest machine is eating CPU.

Any ideas?

Comment: @user535733 I am trying to generate a table like that. I updated a bit, thanks for your reminder.

Comment: Try `top -n 1 -b > text.txt` and see if that's what you're after. That's what I use. The output isn't all that pretty, but it's readable.

Comment: Have you located that PID on the guest? what happens if you kill it

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need is in /proc. But it's raw, unprocessed.

- PID: Simply walk the `proc` tree. It's arranged in /proc/[PID]
- User: /proc/[PID]/loginuid. It's a number, converting it to a name is fairly easy. ([Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38366362/is-there-a-way-to-identify-the-user-who-owns-a-process-from-proc-pid))
- CPU: /proc/[PID]/stat. You need to [calculate the output value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16726779/how-do-i-get-the-total-cpu-usage-of-an-application-from-proc-pid-stat) from the data.
- Command: /proc/[PID]/cmdline

Comment: Thank you. The thing is, I don't know which pid eats cpu before I get the table I'm trying to generate. So, I have to go through the whole `/proc` tree, right?

Comment: Yes, you must walk the whole tree. If you already knew which process was your culprit, then you wouldn't need a table to show you. If you are merely troubleshooting, then you don't need a table...you have a table ('top' output). You didn't say why that "didn't work," but for basic troubleshooting, fixing your parsing problem might be faster than writing your own duplicate.